# RegEx all matches between

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to match all `foo` and `bar` (those who are only between `8` characters) in this text `foo bar foo 8 bar foo bar 8 foo bar foo`.

This is what I tried: `8.*(foo|bar).*8`

The problem is it only matches the last `bar` as (I believe) the greedy quantifier go as far as he can.

I did my best when trying to search for how to fix this but couldn't end up finding anything, so I'm asking here.

My current RegEx so you can understand what I mean better: https://regex101.com/r/p0tQws/1

Comment: It's always good to tag your questions with your language, especially as there are quite a few differences between different regex engines. This problem is relatively easy to solve in PHP, a lot more difficult in JS.

Comment: Can there be words other than `foo` and `bar` between the `8`s?

Comment: @Nick Yes, there can basically be anything

Comment: Things will be easier if variable length look-behind is available but that's not possible in Javascript.  Does it need to be a pure regex solution?

Answer (score 0):

`8([^8]*(foo|bar)+[^8]*)8`

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XlXU5z/2) for explanation

This was the issue, in essence:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. However, this doesn't seem to be what I want. I'd like ``foo`` and ``bar`` to be different matches, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a regex capture would be a `split` and `map` or similar array function:

```
let   str = 'foo bar foo 8 bar foo cruft foo fnooz bar 8 foo bar foo'
let   is8 = false

// split string on spaces 
str.split(/\s/).map(el => {
  // toggle 'is8' when encountered
  if(el == 8)
    is8 = !is8

  // 'is8' is true, and el matches regex
  if(is8 && /(foo|bar)/.test(el)) 
  {        
    // do something with el between the 8's e.g. uppercase
    return el.toUpperCase()
  }
  return el
}).join(' ')

// yields "foo bar foo 8 BAR FOO cruft FOO fnooz BAR 8 foo bar foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match the first `8`, then capture in group 1 what is between the second occurrence of 8 and use a positive lookahead if you also want to get a match if there is another occurrence of 8 following.

If you want the separate parts you could split the data in group 1 on a space.

```
 \b8\s+([^8]+)(?=\s+8\b)
```

- `\b8` Match 8 preceded by a word bounary
- `\s+` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `([^8]+)` Capture group 1, match any char except `8` 1+ times
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `\s+8\b` Match 0+ whitespace chars and match 8 followed by a word boundary
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mkb0Cc/1)

```js
const pattern = /\b8\s+([^8]+)(?=\s+8\b)/;
let str = "foo bar foo 8 bar foo bar 8 foo bar foo";
str = str.match(pattern)[1].split(" ");
console.log(str);
```

---

If you also want to be able to match for example `800` in between, you could use

```
\b8\s+(.+?)(?=\s+8\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MMZLxH/1)

Answer (score 0):

(When trying in regex 101, it seems that it allow non-fix-width look-behind in Javascript.  If this works for you, you may try this)

If your environment allows non-fix-width look-behind, you can try

```
(?<=8.*)(foo|bar)(?=.*8)
Explanation:
(?<=   )                   positive look-behind, i.e. preceded by
    8.*                        8, then zero-or-more character
        (foo|bar)          "foo" or "bar", in capture group
                 (?=   )   postiive look-ahead, i.e. followed by
                    .*8        zero-or-more characters, then 8
```

https://regex101.com/r/p0tQws/3